# C++ question , how can I see the default value of packing

Tags: c++, xcode, structure-packing

I'm a little confused on the current packing scheme in a struct. Take this example

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    char        c;
    double      d;
    int         s;
} Node;



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    cout << sizeof(char) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(double) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(int) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(Node) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
Hello, World!
1
8
4
24
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I understand that there is a certain scheme of packing. However assuming a size of 8. should this be 1+8 +4 + padding shouldn't it be 16, however its being reported as 24.
Is there a way I can find out the default value of packing?
I am currently using a xcode on a mac that's not too old.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731778/compile-time-check-for-usage-of-pragma-pack

Comment: Each member should be correctly aligned, so `char c; /*padding (8 - 1)*/ double d; int s; /*padding(8-4)*/` (last one is needed so consecutive `Node` (array) are correctly aligned.)

Comment: To see exact amount of padding you can print the position of each member using `offsetof` macro.

Comment: The `double` needs 8-byte alignment. Move it first or last and compare the results.

Comment: Thanks guys! The order of variables matters!